# What are the values of a and b such that $a^4 + 4 b^4$ is prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

What values of a and b will ensure $a^4 + 4 b^4$ is prime

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT:

$$a^4+4b^4=(a^2)^2+(2b^2)^2=(a^2+2b^2)^2-2\cdot a^2\cdot2b^2=(a^2+2b^2)^2-(2ab)^2$$

$$=(a^2+2b^2-2ab)(a^2+2b^2+2ab)=\{(a-b)^2+b^2\}\{(a+b)^2+b^2\}$$

For primality one of the two factor must be $=1$

If $(a-b)^2+b^2=1\implies $

Assuming $a,b$ to be integers

either $a-b=\pm1,b=0\implies a=\pm1$

or $a-b=0,b=\pm1\implies a=b=\pm1$